# SignalTap II: OR trigger conditions, instead of AND

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga, debugging

I'm using the Altera SignalTap II that comes with Quartus II. As far as I understand, each pin can be assigned a trigger condition. It seems that acquisition only stops when *all* the trigger conditions are satisfied.

How can I tell SignalTap II to stop acquiring when *any* of the pin trigger conditions I have set occurs?

Comment: In some cases, it's easier to just add some gates to your design to create the trigger you need, rather that trying to coerce the tools into doing something they weren't really designed for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never use SignalTap II, but according to [the docs](http://www.altera.com/literature/hb/qts/qts_qii53009.pdf)  in chapter 13, the "advanced trigger conditions" have the option of a "reduction OR" which seems to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation, in typical Altera style, is appalling.
There are two options for trigger conditions - Basic AND (all trigger selections have to be true), and Basic OR (I'm guessing any one trigger condition is true). None of this is stated in the qii53009. However, when I use it with Basic OR, it seems to trigger as soon as I run it, which seems bizarre, because none of trigger conditions are met. So maybe there is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by default SignalTap II will use the "Basic AND" setting which behaves as you might imagine when you specify multiple triggers--it requires them all to be active in the same clock cycle for the trigger to fire.

You don't need to go to the trouble of configuring an "Advanced" trigger if all you want is to OR your triggers conditions.  Instead, in the setup window where you add the signals you want to tap, at the top of the table in the Trigger Conditions column there is a drop-down.  Just select "Basic OR" in that drop down and recompile.

I've gotten into the habit of changing this setting to "Basic OR" first thing when I'm creating a new capture configuration.  I wish it was the default as it seems to be what I need 90% of the time.

More info: SignalTap II triggering can take a little getting used to, especially if your coming from the Xilinx ChipScope world.  The short of is that you can create SignalTap triggers that are much more sophisticated than what you can do get with ChipScope, BUT, you have to do it before you compile the design.  ChipScope is more flexible at run-time with less work but ultimately gives you fewer triggering options.